# Cookies with jQuery - First visit load html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

**As the title already tells; Cookies with jQuery - *First visit load html page.***

Got the following code which gives me the following error in Chrome's developer tool logger: *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('visited')
    if (visited == null) {
        $(page.html).show();
    } else {
        $(page.html).hide();
    }
    $.cookie('visited', 'yes_visited', {
        expires: 1,
        path: '/'
    });
});
```

First of all I wonder why i get this error for line 2 in this code.
Secondly i have no idea how to load an page in Javascript.

Any explanation would be very appreciated! :)

Comment: You did not include the jQuery Cookie plugin? It's not in the jQuery core plugin.

Comment: which can be linked to from this CDN -> http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Cookies.js/0.3.1/cookies.js

Comment: I've been looking for an solution all the time, mostly on here.. Nobody ever spoke about this plugin. Although it seems kind of logic there's a plugin for this. Thanks for helping me out, feel kind of dumb right now haha

Comment: This one can be closed i guess?

Comment: It will be closed with time :)